# When converting NSData to unsigned char*, I get the wrong result

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, nsdata, unsigned-char

I would like to convert an `UIImage` into `unsigned char*`. First I convert `UIImage` into `NSData`, then `NSData` to `unsigned char*`. I use the following method to convert `NSData` to `unsigned char*`:

```
unsigned char *binaryData = (unsigned char *)[imageData bytes];
```

The problem is that there are many many bytes in `imageData` (which is an `NSData`), but after the method, the binaryData is just `0x75e8000`. I have no idea why. Could anybody help me out there? And can you suggest me one way to correctly convert `NSData` to `unsigned char*`?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: How are you checking the "contents" of binaryData?  By default, the debugger will treat that as a C string, which will stop printing when it reaches a NULL byte.  Alternatively, that value could be the pointer itself, but that would change every time you ran the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you understand what a C array is. It is represented as a pointer into the start of the array. Your `0x75e8000` *is* the start of the array. But the array contains no information about its length; how much more data there may be is unknown.

Also, you may not understand what the `bytes` method is. The `bytes` method does not "convert" anything, nor does it generate a copy; it merely provides a pointer into the NSData itself. As long as the NSData exists, the `bytes` points at it, but treats it as a `const void*` (which you are casting to an `unsigned char*`), suitable for handing to a C function.

So, the length of the C array, which you would need to tell any C function that uses this information, must be obtained separately; it is the `length` of the NSData object. And if you want to *extract* the data, as a copy, into a *separate* C array, then call `getBytes:length:`.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is more explicit than just posting code.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {

        [self test];
    }

    - (void)test {

        // Put a picture named "test.jpg" in your app bundle
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"jpg"];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
        char buffer[data.length];

        // Print them out
        [data getBytes:buffer length:data.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            printf("0x%02x ",(unsigned char)buffer[i]);
        }
    }
```